# com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length 4552032 is less than the maximum message length 4194304

Tags: java, mongodb

One of the MongoDB collection has some 8K records in them. I want to fetch all the documents from the db

1. First I tried to get records in this fashion. But after fetching some 4K records it threw this exception

**com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length 4552032 is less than the maximum message length 4194304**

```
MongoCursor<Document> documentMongoCursor = mongoCollection
                    .find()
                    .batchSize(50)
                    .cursor();

while (documentMongoCursor.hasNext()) {
  Document document = documentMongoCursor.next();
  //procsess document
}
```

When I debug, found out that cursor is batching up records with 101 count. So I thought to batch with 50 count, but got the same error too.

2. Tried to apply limit and fetch the data in pages, but got the same error again. It fetched well for a while and failed after 3K records.

```
MongoCursor<Document> documentMongoCursor = mongoCollection
                    .find()
                    .batchSize(50)
                    .limit(1000)
                    .cursor();

while (documentMongoCursor.hasNext()) {
  Document document = documentMongoCursor.next();
  //procsess document
}
```

I am using **mongodb-java-driver 3.11** version and hoping that the driver will handle all such error. 
I am not sure how to resolve the issue efficiently. Any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.